# Windows Git Bash sets SHELL environment variable incorrectly for invoked Python

Tags: python, windows, bash, git

I open "Git Bash" (git version 2.21.0.windows.1) and print the SHELL env variable, it displays **bash**.

```
$ echo $SHELL
bash
```

But doing the same with python (either version 2 or 3), results in:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.environ['SHELL'])
C:\Users\serj\bash
```

For some reason it prepends the current directory and the result is bogus, as there's no bash there. All other env variables are OK.

If this is a bug, how do I go about knowing if I should report to Python, git or MSYS ? Regular MSYS+python do work, so seems something special in this git package.

Comment: `SHELL` is `/usr/bin/bash` here, same WinGit version. Are you starting Bash with "Git Bash" shortcut? Did you override this variable?

Comment: I suspect you may have some `.bash*` in `%USERPROFILE%` from Cygwin or something, or there's otherwise something funny in your system configuration (e.g. custom symlinks).

Comment: I'm starting bash with the desktop icon shortcut, yes. I didn't override the variable, and it displays fine with echo, it's just python that's acting funny

Comment: Read my post(s) carefully. Did you notice it has a full path for me? The lack of a full path (that you report) is not normal.

Comment: Understood now, I found an "export SHELL=bash" in an old .bash_profile.

I wonder why the bash.exe from my standalone MSYS2 installation doesn't have this behaviour (doesn't prepend cwd), while "Git Bash" does it.

Anyway, thanks, I can make progress now!

Comment: MSYS2 doesn't use `%USERPROFILE%` as its `$HOME` ([but can be configured so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942924/how-to-change-home-directory-and-start-directory-on-msys2)), so a `.bash_profile` there won't affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $ echo $SHELL
> bash
> ```

This is not normal. It should be `/usr/bin/bash`. Something must be wrong with your system configuration or the way you are starting Git Bash. E.g.:

- The shortcut is wrong and starting it with incorrect environment. (For me, it points to `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home`, and current directory is `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.)
- You have some custom Bash startup scripts in `%USERPROFILE%` that override `SHELL` (e.g. you also have Cygwin and have pointed its `$HOME` to your `%USERPROFILE%`, too).
- There are some custom configuration changes in Git's MinGW environment (e.g. in its `/etc`), or disk layout changes, e.g. custom symlinks, or environment variables are set at Windows level that alter MinGW's behavior.