# How to run msys2 separately from git?

Tags: git, msys2

I have windows 7 64 bit, and git use mingw shell as well as msys2.

I need to setup a different HOME path for msys2, but to keep it the default for git.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think MSYS2 allow you to define a new $HOME variable.
MSys2 doesn't let you create different users either.